# Is using the word "Incredible" to mean that a claim is invalid or incorrect common and acceptable among English speakers/writers?

Tags: meaning-in-context

My understanding is that the term is typically used to reference an unbelievable event or occurrence.

However, since the "in-" prefix typically represents a negation of sorts, is it acceptable to use it in the follow manner:

> Person_A: "The newest evidence indicates that one plus one equals two."
>
> Person_B: "Prior, unshaken evidence indicates that one plus one cannot logically equal two. Therefore, your claim is mathematically incredible."

Comment: Just a quick 'net search through a [handful](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incredible) of [dictionaries](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/incredible) [shows](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/incredible) this to be one of the definitions.  However, I suspect you are really asking about nuance and whether this is a common and accepted usage.  If you don't want your question closed for lack of research, you should consider re-phrasing it (and include at least one dictionary link).

Comment: *Incredible* can also mean *amazing*. *Not credible* is unambiguous and, perhaps, a better choice.

Comment: When you edit that research in have a look at what you actually asking. Currently it's unclear if you are just wondering about the usage of the word in general or if you have something specific in mind. The [tag:meaning-in-context] tag is reserved for specific contexts in longer passages of English.

Comment: Although I accepted the edit to the title, you need to edit the question itself as well. Also, you appear to have more than one account: you can get them merged by ensuring that one is registered and following the [Help pages' advice](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Did you look at the definition of "[credible](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/credible)":  *Able to be believed; convincing.*  "Incredible" means the opposite -- unbelievable.  While it could be used as you suggest, I suspect that's not quite catching the meaning you desire.  Something like "illogical" may be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

As already noted in a comment, the meaning you seek is given as a possible definition by several dictionaries.  For example, [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incredible) lists:

> too extraordinary and improbable to be believed

I'm going to answer using the following example sentence

> As the jury deliberated, they considered Joe to be a/an __________ witness.

Let's consider substituting one of four words into the blank, one at a time:

**Believable** implies that the jury accepted what Joe said, and that his testimony was truthful.

**Credible** is essentially the same as believable, but when I read it back, it seems stronger, suggesting an even greater level of trust in Joe.

**Unbelievable** does not automatically make one think either untruthful nor truthful.  In fact, it reads to me as Joe was phenomenally informative, and gave very important and useful information in determining the verdict.

**Incredible** is admittedly ambiguous, but I am more likely to read this the same as unbelievable describe above then anything else, unless additional context is given.

To be clear, if I wanted to convey the opposite idea, that the jury thought Joe was lying, I would put the negation with the verb, rather than the adjective:

> As the jury deliberated, they considered Joe to *not* be a credible witness.